# How to know the length of the visible part of an overflowing element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a table having many rows ; so the table is overflowing the document viewport vertical axis :

[image]

As you can see : only a part of the table is displayed on document ready. So how to know the length of that part ?

Comment: calculated using js?

Comment: what are the functions for that ?

Comment: I don't there there is something inbuilt like that. But it's easy to calculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JS to find the height of the table and subtract it from the height of the window.

```
var tableHeight = document.getElementById('myTable').clientHeight;
var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

console.log('Height of visible table: ', tableHeight - winHeight);
```

Comment: just a remark : I got `TypeError: document.window is undefined` , so I removed keyword `document` :)

Comment: @pheromix I fixed that now for the OP

Comment: @pheromix Well, ShatteredRib, I was actually fixing the `document.window` issue ... and pheromix, "the OP" stands for _the original poster_